# How to add condition for a field in the layout of SuiteCRM.?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

In that in studio I have created some fields in one module and i also add those fields in Layout. but i want to display the fields according to the selection, for example: if user select **option-1** from dropdown field then it has to display say only three field, and if user select **option-2** from dropdown field then it has to display say six fields. so i need to add some condition in the layout field. but i can't find any option there.. please help me to find out. 
i also attached the example image below.

[image: one]

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the view definitions to add a script into the edit view of your module.

**Example:**

```
$viewdefs ['<Module Name>'] =
    array(
       '<View Name>View' =>
           array(
               'templateMeta' =>
                   array(
                       ...
                       'includes' =>
                           array(
                               0 =>
                                   array(
                                       'file' => 'path/to/your/script.js',
                                   ),
                               1 =>
                                   array(
                                       'file' => 'path/to/your/script.js',
                                   ),
                           ),
                       ...
                   ),
                   ...
           ),
           ...
   );
```

You then can use jQuery or any javascript library to hide or show the fields. if you are using SuiteR or SuiteP theme you can simply add/remove the hidden class to the elements.

Just make sure that you add all the fields into your view which you wish to show or hide.

To make this upgrade save modify or create

- custom/modules/module name/metadata/editviewdefs.php for the edit view
- custom/modules/module name/metadata/detailviewdefs.php for the detail view

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sugar 7.6  I can help,

You want to change the fields according to drop down values if i am not wrong .
For that you have to right a code in "record.js" and "create-actions.js" files . just write a js function.
This is an example for crerate-action.js

```
({
    extendsFrom: 'CreateActionsView',
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.model.on("change:dropdown", this.renderFields, this);
    },

    renderFields: function () {

        // write your code here

    },


})
```

Comment: Amitesh, think you could pop into a chat for me to help figure this out for a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

There are many defined ways in sugarcrm, as you have created new fields, all you need to add dependencies on those fields like

```
$dictionary['YOUR_MODULE_NAME']['fields']['YOUR_FIELD_NAME']['dependency']='(equal($YOUR_DROPDOWN,"OPTION_1"))
```

see
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.7/Architecture/Sugar_Logic/Dependency_Actions/SetVisibility/#Visibility_Dependencies_in_Field_Definitions

This can also be added through Studio.
Go to *Studio > module > fields > YOUR_FIELD > Dependent* and add dependency.

Comment: I think this only applies to SugarCRM, not SuiteCRM. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sure about SugarCRM, but not sure about SuitCRM